# Какое есть более выразительное слово для обозначение термина КУЛЬТУРА в первом смысле?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, синонимы

Насколько мы знаем, термин культура имеет как минимум 2 значения:
1. Культура — совокупность достижений человечества в производственном, общественном и духовном отношении. архитектура, музыка, мифология.
2. Культура — то же, что культурность. "Человек высокой культуры".

Есть слово сеттинг, то есть может быть, например, обстановка мебели в доме 19 века, или средневековья, или современная.

Но как сказать, что культура Франции лучше культуры Англии? Получается неоднозначно.
А сказать "Сеттинг Франции лучше сеттинга Англии" язык не поворачивается
Хочется привязать это именно как достижение страны.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

**Франция достигла более высокого уровня развития культуры, чем Англия.**

Comment: да я же имею ввиду не второе, а первое. тоесть это не скалярная величина.

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях как правило используют что-то вроде *Англия имела менее развитую культуру*.

Ещё можно использовать термин "высокий/низкий уровень культуры". *Франция по сравнению с Англией имела более высокий уровень культуры*.

Лучше/хуже по отношении к культуре использовать не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

**Франция более цивилизованная страна, чем Англия.**

Пример: Отсталая, сравнительно невежественная Италия легче отступилась от папы, чем **более цивилизованная, передовая Франция** [К. Н. Леонтьев. Письма отшельника (1879)]

Answer (score 0):

> А сказать "Сеттинг Франции лучше сеттинга Англии" язык не
>   поворачивается

Это хорошо, потому что это означало бы примерно следующее: начальные условия, в которых находится (находилась) Франция, лучше, чем у Англии.

Можно было бы сказать так: "цивилизация А была лучше цивилизации Б", но это можно говорить о культурах (цивилизациях) прошлого и только при условии, что где-то рядом чётко сформулированы критерии сравнения.

Comment: цивиллизация это слишком большое что-то, например цивиллизация Европы, Восточная цивиллизация, Азиатская цивиллизация.

Comment: @ДанилаЛетуновский Попытайтесь набрать в Гугле "цивилизация Франции", "цивилизация Англии" и т.п. Посмотрите на контекст, может подойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку речь идёт не об отдельных аспектах культуры, для которых существуют общепризнанные стереотипы  (например, о сравнении французской кухни с английской), то, если вы хотите, чтобы с вашей оценкой специалиста по сравнительной культурологии считались, можно сказать так:

**Культура Франции мне ближе и интереснее, чем культура Англии. Основываясь на своих знаниях, опыте и обширных сравнительных исследованиях, культуру Франции я ставлю неизмеримо выше.**

Если же вы попытаетесь сформулировать такое положение как *объективную* оценку, оно может вызвать недоумение и прозвучать так:

> Культура Франции лучше, чем культура Англии. Чем? Чем культура Англии.